# Gitlab-CI Runner HTTP Basic Access denied with private repo (self-hosted)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

This is the output I get by clicking `show complete raw` because the normal view is just 1 black line (no log inside).

I tried what https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/ci/ssh_keys/README.md says, but with no luck.

I have a server with two docker containers: one with gitlab, the other with gitlab-runner. I have tested with shared runner and with a specific runner (like the code I show below). In both cases is the same: it fails because it cannot fetch my repository.

It only works (both shared and specific runners) if I set my repo public (neither private, nor internal). And I would like to work with a private repo.

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ecf97f)
  on runner-myrepo-js (900c71a4)
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image node:latest ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image sha256:46da793b60ee30f8df451729e315f531f0acd24a92c8fba10401513530beff99 for predefined container...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image node:latest ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image node:latest ID=sha256:cbea0ebe4f3cf07daecf22b196ba6b5d76d1fe1b6548098e5bc9dd9b0736f262 for build container...
[0;msection_start:1509656546:prepare_script
[0KRunning on runner-900c71a4-project-32-concurrent-0 via a16b07f5f84b...
section_end:1509656548:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1509656548:get_sources
[0K[32;1mCloning repository...[0;m
Cloning into '/builds/gitlab/myuser/myrepo-js'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://example.com/gitlab/myuser/myrepo-js.git/'
section_end:1509656549:get_sources
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

What should I do?

I have both gitlab and gitlab-runner in version 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were struggling today and definetely it is a problem of SSL:

Our frontend used SSL certificates, but the backend (gitlab) used plain HTTP (behind a proxy). This broke the real-time log of jobs and the access to private repos from runners.

Adding the SSLs and forcing HTTPS in the backend solved the problem.

Comment: And how did you do that ? :)